# How do I make it so people can't vote twice on a Discord poll system?

Tags: discord, discord.net

I have a Discord Bot which has a poll system. The Discord bot can create multiple polls and store the data in a .json file. The only problem with this is people can vote twice for a single poll. How do I make it so a person can't vote twice for a single poll? This may seem like a simple question, however, I can't find a way to solve this.

Comment: Don't know why this question was downvoted without reasoning. Even if it was a dupe (which I haven't checked), it should be marked as dupe, or even commented. It's a valid question. It's worded exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in the JSON file called "voted" and whenever someone votes, add their Discord ID to the array. Whenever someone tries to vote, check if their ID already exists in the "voted" array.

NOTE: This will not prevent users from creating spam accounts just to vote.